# What do the suffixes "+" and "-" after the job id of background jobs mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When I run several background processes my output of the command `jobs` is for example:

```
[1]-  RUNNING                  nohup somecommand1 &
[2]+  RUNNING                  nohup somecommand2 &
```

What do the "+" and "-" chars after the job id mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's in the man-page for jobs under STDOUT:

```
> man jobs
```

> The character '+' identifies the job that would be used as a default for the fg or bg utilities; this job can also be specified using the job_id %+ or "%%" . The character '-' identifies the job that would become the default if the current default job were to exit; this  job  can  also  be  specified using  the  job_id  %-.

So the job marked with '+' is the one that will be activated by 'fg'.

Comment: Thanks! You certainly have the better linux distribution. When I hit `man jobs` I only get a very brief description of the parameters.

Comment: That's interesting, what distribution are you running?
I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: Scientific Linux, which is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I get a general `bash` manual page and the section for `jobs` is just a list of parameters. No STDOUT.

Comment: This answer is useful in combination with @bos's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564598/5478086).

Answer (score 6):

The + means that that process was the last one running before putting in background. The - means it was the second to last before putting in background.

If you do "fg" your job number 2 (the +) will be put into foreground, unless you explicitly state "fg %1", which will put the job with the - into foreground.

Example:

```
rock:$ sleep 30m &
[1] 25808
[1002 ~]
rock:$ sleep 45m &
[2] 25813
[1003 ~]
rock:$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 30m &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 45m &
[1004 ~]
rock:$ fg
sleep 45m
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 45m
[1005 ~]
rock:$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 30m &
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 45m
[1006 ~]
rock:$ fg %1
sleep 30m
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30m
[1007 ~]
rock:$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30m
[2]-  Stopped                 sleep 45m
```

Pay attention to the last rows, where + and - changed places.